# Can IIS Express run from Visual Studio respond to any hostname for a given port (and sensibly tracked in source)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I have an MVC 5 web project that can be run from Visual Studio. This works fine and the relevant web section in the project files looks like this.

[image: web settings]

However this creates a binding that is explicitly tied to localhost **and** 60163, whereas I'd like to just be tied to the port.

I've been able to do this by editing the bindings `applicationHost.config` in the `.vs` folder by adding the binding below.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:60164:*" />
```

However this folder is (rightfully I believe) not tracked in source control, so I can't share this change with my team.

Is there any way I could achieve this without editing the contents of the `.vs` folder?

Comment: Isn't possible for you to use the Local IIS setting and just create the Project Uri without a port? This way you don't need to worry about port anymore. Simply add `http://localhost/ServiceName` and hit create virtual directory button. Save the changes and commit. The rest of your team don't need to create that Uri because it will automatically create once they debug.

Comment: It may be but it's specifically the port to be locked down that I'm looking for.